# Drawing triangle with correct side length and angles

Tags: trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, plane-geometry, angle

So I have the following question:

You have a triangle with one angle that is $135°$. The opposite side is $2 *\sqrt{{10}}$ and the adjacent side is $2 *\sqrt{{2}}$.

I used Pythagoras equation and got $4 *\sqrt{{3}}$

My problem is I dont know how I would draw my triangle with the exact angles and sides measurement that is given.

[image]

Comment: You cannot apply Pythagoras theorem here, as it is not a right angle triangle. You would have to use the sine law.

Comment: oh then it makes more sense to why I got the question wrong then

Comment: Or the law of cosines : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines

Comment: If your aim is to draw the triangle (by straightedge and compass??) then there is no need to find the remaining side. I'm confused by the discrepancy between the question and the comments.

Comment: I don't find $4\sqrt 3$ for the last side.

Comment: @Bernard  Yes, of course. It's equal to $4$. See my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\Delta ABC$ be our triangle, $\measuredangle ABC=135^{\circ},$ $BC=2\sqrt2$, $AC=2\sqrt{10}$

and let $CD$ be an altitude of $\Delta ABC.$

Thus, $BD=CD=2$ and we can draw $\Delta ACD$ and from here we can draw $\Delta ABC.$

Comment: Could you provide an image to your answer I really get lost when  the question says  opposite or adjacent side I cant seem to visualize it in my head

Comment: @zellez I don't know to draw in the net. Try to draw the angle with a measure $135^{\circ}$ and after this you can draw the triangle. Actually, the altitude is placed outside the triangle.

Comment: I put an image dont know if that is how you ordered them

Comment: @zellez You drew a acute-angled  triangle. Draw an obtuse-angled triangle with $\measuredangle ABC=135^{\circ}.$

Comment: sry for the late answer was asleep, I get it now didnt use the exact order but this should do